# cloud function Not all code paths return a value still I am returning all values possible?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

any idea why my cloud function is telling my that (Not all code paths return a value) I put a return on the promise at the end also on the  if statement yet it is not working, I read about similar issues tried to solve according to them but I still missing part of the puzzle, the error started showing when I wrapped the whole thing with try-catch.

```js
export const createClient = functions.https.onCall(async(data, context) => {
  try {

    const snapshotCheckBelong = await db.collection('data-    main').doc(data.sharedId).get();
    const getClient = snapshotCheckBelong.data() ? .clients.filter((el: any) => el.clientId === data.clientId);

    const snapshotCheckExist = await db.collection('data-registered-clients').doc(data.sharedId).get();
    const checkClient = snapshotCheckExist.data() ? .clients.filter((el: any) => el.clientId === data.clientId);

    if (checkClient[0]) {
      return {
        result: 'Registered client already exisits.'
      };
    }

    if (getClient[0] ? .clientId === data.clientId && checkClient.length === 0) {
      const payload = {
        user: 'client',
        verifiedEmail: false,
        createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now(),
      };

      let auth = admin
        .auth()
        .getUserByEmail(context.auth ? .token ? .email!)
        .then((user) =>
          admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
            userType: 'client',
            premiumUnitll: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(snapshotCheckBelong.data() ? .premiumUntill)
          })
        )
        .catch((err: any) => {
          console.log(err);
        });

      let setClientData = db
        .collection('data-clients')
        .doc(context.auth ? .uid!)
        .set(payload)
        .catch((err: any) => {
          console.log(err);
        });

      let updateRegisteredClients = db
        .collection('data-registered-clients')
        .doc(data.sharedId)
        .update({
          clients: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
            clientAccount: context.auth ? .uid,
            clientId: data.clientId,
            trainerId: data.sharedId
          })
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
          console.log(err);
        });

      return Promise.all([auth, setClientData, updateRegisteredClients]);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } catch {
    (err: any) => {
      console.log(err);
    };
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `catch` blocks are not returning anything. If you handle an error with `catch`, you have to determine what value gets returned to the caller.

I typically prefer sending the error back to the caller, as shown in the documentation on [handling errors in callable cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors) and on the [calling client](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors_on_the_client).

Comment: I tried this before posting and even now still the same

Comment: If I return after the catch the function errors out on deployment

Comment: "I tried this before posting" Instead of telling us that now, show in your question how you did that. With what you posted now, the lack of return values in `catch` blocks is at least one of the causes of this problem.